# How to store userid, roleid and privilegeid in single table using @JoinTable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

**Requirement :** Create table using @JoinColumn annotation in User entity class, which contain columns like, user_id, authority_id(means role), privilege_id.

**Condition:** Authority and Privileges also have one to many relationship.

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "pm_authority_privilege",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Privilege> privileges = new HashSet<>();
```

As per above configuration i got privilege as part of authority json.

**Issue :** I'm confused what should be variable type if i take two value in 'inverseJoinColumns'.

When i try to do same thing using following way it gives error of transactional object because privilege is exist on two place.

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "pm_user_authority_privilege",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    // @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    })
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "pm_user_authority_privilege",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Privilege> privileges = new HashSet<>();
```

**Note :** There is page which have no. of roles and all relevant privilege of those role.(handle using code define in issue)

And from that i select some of role and save them when user created.

```
{
 "authorities": [
   {
     "authorityId": "ec071816-31e6-11ea-bae1-0242ac110005",
     "authorityName": "MANAGER",
     "description": null,
     "privileges": [
       {
         "description": "",
         "privilege": "CREATE_USER",
         "privilegeId": "ba9a4952-4d53-42e9-94fe-8373d334819e"
       },
       {
         "description": null,
         "privilege": "SHOW_DATA",
         "privilegeId": "ec06de1b-31e6-11ea-bae1-0242ac110005"
       }
     ]
   }
 ],
 "email": "test@gmail.com",
 "password": "test@123",
 "phoneNo": "8575456595",
 "status": true,
 "userId": null,
 "username": "test"
}
```

Comment: Add the JSON to the question

Comment: @Rohit check now.

Comment: You will need `OnetoMany` relationship from `User` to `Authority` and another `OnetoMany` relationship from `Authority` to `Privilege`.

Comment: Your privileges are on authorities not on users.

Comment: @Rohit First of all thanks for giving an answer. But you suggest me that way which i already do. My question is what should i do for implement that kind of scenario. In brief, Authority have multiple privileges but we're not providing all privileges to all users we provide selected  one. And there is not any direct relationship between user and privileges that's why i want to bind privilege_id in table 'pm_user_authority_privilege'

Comment: If you want to assign `Privilege` directly to `User` and also via `Authority`, then you need 2 different relationships from the `User`. And both cannot use the same table. BTW, the privileges to user is missing in your json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found something. It is not up to the mark but it help solve your problem.

As per i understand you need two kind of relationship,

1. Authority & Privileges
2. User & Authority & Privileges (Privileges also exist in Authority object)

In such case you have to follow this,

1. Create one UserDTO which access user info and authority JSON (So privilege not show two times).
2. Based on that JSON create two entity and their object. One for User and another for UserAuthorityPrivilege.
3. UserAuthorityPrivilege is the table which contain your three required data and as obvious all three are required so define them as embedded key.
4. Give the relation between user and UserAuthorityPrivilege table

### Embaded Class :

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmbeddedUserAccess implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "user_id")   private UUID userId;

  @Column(name = "authority")   private String authority;

  @Column(name = "privilege")   private String privilege;  }
```

### Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pm_user_authority_privilege")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserAuthorityPrivilege {
  @EmbeddedId
  private EmbeddedUserAccess id;

  @Null
  @Column(name = "store_id", nullable = true)
  private UUID storeId;
}
```

### DTO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDTO {

  private UUID userId;
  private String username;
  private String email;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private String password;
  private Boolean status;
  private Authority authority;
}
```

### Fetch:

```
UserAuthorityPrivilege access = null;
      EmbeddedUserAccess embedded = null;
      Set<UserAuthorityPrivilege> accessibilities = new HashSet<>();
      Authority authority = userDTO.getAuthority();
      for (Privilege privilege : authority.getPrivileges()) {
        access = new UserAuthorityPrivilege();
        embedded = new EmbeddedUserAccess();
        embedded.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        embedded.setAuthority(authority.getAuthority());
        embedded.setPrivilege(privilege.getPrivilege());
        access.setId(embedded);
        accessibilities.add(access);
      }
```

You have to update code similerly.

I have one query, your user relate with single authority or multiple.

For more brief description add comment.

Comment: Thanks for answer i think about this but not implemented search about some other solutions. I definatly try this one i suppose it works but it become grate if i able to implement using @JoinTable.

Comment: No currently based on my requirement i there is only one authority allocate to single user.